# Adding enties from php to JS array using push method and object properties

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a function that has to receive data from DB on Server and push it into the array. That is:

```
function Preload() {
  var valueToPush = {};
  var userID1 = '<?php echo $id_user;?>';
  $.ajax({

    url: 'TR.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      userID1: userID1
    },
    success: function(data) {

      var names = data
      $('#result_div_id').html(data);
      var json2 = $.parseJSON(data);
      EntriesCount = json2.length;
      $(json2).each(function(i, val) {
        $.each(val, function(k, v) {

          switch (k) {
            case 'Name':
              valueToPush.Name = v;

            case 'Phone':
              valueToPush.Phone = v;
          }
          name2.push(valueToPush);
        });
      });
      currententry = 0;
    }
  });

}
}
```

But this code is adding an only one entry in array. Other entries are undefined... What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tag php dude ;)

Comment: You must, really really must, study some JS syntax. For starters, you need to break each `case` otherwise the code will continue evaluating. Add `break;` at the end of each `case`

Comment: To  Ruby Racer:

Thanx, I did it! But, now it fill my array this way:

name2[1][Name] = Vasya, name2[2][Name] = Vasya, name2[3][Name] = Vasya, name2[4][Name] = Bob, ...and so on...

But in my DB the picture is:

name2[1][Name] = Vasya, name2[2][Name] = Bob, name2[3][Name] = John, name2[4][Name] = Anna, ... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are pushing to **name2** on the wrong place. You should do this on the first iteration.

---

Edit: after getting an example of your JSON i guess the second iteration is not needed after all. So I rewrote my final code below.

**The final code would be like this:**

```
function Preload() {
    var userID1 = '<?php echo $id_user;?>';
    $.ajax({

        url: 'TR.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            userID1: userID1
        },
        success: function(data) {

            var names = data;
            $('#result_div_id').html(data);
            var json2 = $.parseJSON(data);
            EntriesCount = json2.length;
            $.each(json2, function(i, val) {
                var valueToPush = {
                    Name: val.Name,
                    Phone: val.Phone
                };
                // if you want to copy all values just do
                // name2.push(val);
                name2.push(valueToPush);
            });
            currententry = 0;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: I guess the second iteration isn't really necessary, like @Ruby Racer said, it may have some errors too. But first we should see how is your is json coming from TR.php.

Comment: 1. I wrote the JSON in this question 2 minutes ago.
2. Your code don't work. Its a pitty (

Comment: Now the code push just an only last entry in my DB. )

Comment: Does it push x times the same entry? If this is the case you should restart the object on each iteration. Like this var valueToPush = {}; on first line after each json2 iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To Pedro Valentim:

My JSON is:

```
[{"ID_Clients":"87","Name":"\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f","Phone":"1234578","Status":"4","Birthday":"2016-10-21","ClientFrom":"4","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"88","Name":"\u041f\u0435\u0442\u044f","Phone":"2345669","Status":"3","Birthday":"2016-10-11","ClientFrom":"2","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"89","Name":"\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0448\u043a\u0430","Phone":"7897574","Status":"3","Birthday":"2016-10-01","ClientFrom":"2","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"142","Name":"888","Phone":"8","Status":"7","Birthday":"0000-00-00","ClientFrom":"3","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"143","Name":"9998888555","Phone":"6","Status":"5","Birthday":"0000-00-00","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"145","Name":"333","Phone":"6","Status":"3","Birthday":"0000-00-00","ClientFrom":"3","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"146","Name":"66","Phone":"66","Status":"1","Birthday":"2016-11-16","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"151","Name":"\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f","Phone":"1234578","Status":"8","Birthday":"2016-10-03","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"158","Name":"999","Phone":"999","Status":"2","Birthday":"2001-12-12","ClientFrom":"2","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"194","Name":"NEW CLIENT","Phone":"+7936000344","Status":"1","Birthday":"2016-11-02","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"195","Name":"NEW CLIENT","Phone":"+7936000344","Status":"1","Birthday":"2016-11-02","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"},{"ID_Clients":"196","Name":"NEW CLIENT","Phone":"+7916120648","Status":"1","Birthday":"2016-11-02","ClientFrom":"1","User":"2"}]
```

and now i will try to fix the array pushing place. Thanx a lot!